# Integral solutions to $A^2=(u^2+uv+2)/2$, $B^2=(v^2+uv+2)/2$, $C^2=1+uv$

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

The system of equations $A^2=(u^2+uv+2)/2$, $B^2=(v^2+uv+2)/2$, $C^2=1+uv$ has $A,B,C,u,v$ all integral.
Numerical evidence found by brute force computation implies that $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16)=0$.
Certainly solving this equation gives an infinite number of solutions so it is sufficient, however I am unable to prove it is necessary. (Solving involves using either $X^2-2Y^2=1$ or $X^2-3Y^2=1$ and standard Pell techniques.)
So can anyone help show that ALL solutions are given by $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16)=0$

Edit

This question is a formulation of Problem 10622 in American Mathematical Monthly 1997 p870. The problem only asks for an infinite number of solutions, I want to find all of them.

My approach is first to note that $0\le C^2=1+uv$ implies $uv\ge-1$.

$uv=0$ gives if $u=v=0$, $A^2=B^2=C^2=1$ as solutions. $u=0,v\ne0$ gives $A^2=C^2=1$ and$$2B^2-v^2=2$$noting that this implies $2\mid v$ then gives$$B^2-2(\frac{v}{2})^2=1$$and standard Pell techniques gives all solutions. Obviously $u\ne0,v=0$ is similar. This provides all solutions to the $uv=0$ part of $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16=0$.

$uv=-1$ gives $C=0$ and $u=\pm1,v=\mp1$ hence $A^2=B^2=1$ as solutions. In this case $u^2-14uv+v^2=16$.

Now noting that $u$ and $v$ cannot have opposite signs (except $uv=-1$ above) and the symmetry of the system of equations means we can limit to $u,v>0$ and change signs to get a complete set. The symmetry also means that we can assume $0<u\le v$ wlog.

$u=v$ implies $C^2=1+u^2$ which gives $u=v=0$ which has already been covered. Hence we can now just look at $0<u<v$ and show that necessarily $u^2-14uv+v^2=16$.

1. For all $u,v$ we have $u^2-14uv+v^2\equiv0\pmod{16}$. This can be shown, if need be,  by looking at all 256 possibilities.
2. For all $u,v$,$$A^2=(\frac{v-3u}{4})^2-(\frac{u^2-14uv+v^2-16}{16})$$$$B^2=(\frac{3v-u}{4})^2-(\frac{u^2-14uv+v^2-16}{16})$$$$C^2=(\frac{u+v}{4})^2-(\frac{u^2-14uv+v^2-16}{16}),$$which show that $u^2-14uv+v^2=16$ is sufficient.

I have found no other way forward that doesn't simply provide tautologies or dead ends. Hopefully this will all help someone else find some inspiration!

Comment: Do you know a nonzero integral solution $(u,v)$? Ah, $u=56,v=4$ and $A=41$, $B=11$, $C=15$. And you said you have shown that every nontrivial solution to your system satisfies $u^2-14uv+v^2-16=0$. So this condition is already necessary.

Comment: No, Every solution to $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16)=0$ is a solution to the system but I cannot show they are all the solutions.

Comment: Then you should note write "implies that $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16)=0$", it if might not be implied.

Comment: It is the numerical evidence that implies $uv(u^2-14uv+v^2-16)=0$

Comment: "Implies" is too strong. I suppose it "suggests" it.

Comment: @coolbear, It seems $(A,B,C)=( -1/4v+3/4u,\  3/4v-1/4u,\ (u+v)/4)$ with $u^2-14uv+v^2-16=0$.

Comment: Yes but why is $u^2-14uv+v^2-16=0$

Answer (score 1):

I thought to find out why $x^2 - 14 xy + y^2$  is involved, perhaps this is the source of the problem:   if
$$  x^2 - 14 xy+ y^2 = 16 - \delta  $$   we find
$$ 16(1 + xy) = \delta + (x+y)^2   $$
$$ 8(x^2 + xy + 2) = \delta + (3x-y)^2   $$
$$ 8(y^2 + xy + 2) = \delta + (-x+3y)^2   $$

Which leads us to ask:   what can we say when $ \; r^2 + \delta, \;  s^2 + \delta, \;  t^2 + \delta \; , \; \;$   are all squares?  Here $\delta$ may be positive or negative. Maybe just inequalities  to continue

next thought. $x+y$   is the average of $3x-y$   and $-x+3y$

Well, not that restrictive, $13^2 + 120 $   and $7^2 + 120$  and $1^2 + 120$ are all squares.    Then
$27^2 -504 $   and $25^2 -504$  and $23^2 -504$ are all squares.

Comment: Thanks for having a go. I'm not sure if I should edit my OP with some of the stuff I have found in case it points people in the wrong direction. Your input would be welcome.  I have tried many different attacks including yours but only find myself with circular or dead end results. My initial thoughts were to get rid of edge cases where $uv=-1,0$ and then concentrate on $u^2-14uv+v^2-16$.

Comment: @coolbear  the main thing is more background for the problem